# Laravel3: Giving failsafe image paths with built-in functions of Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-3

```
background-image: url('home_assets/images/origami/parallax/01.png');
<img alt="" src="home_assets/images/origami/logo.png">
```

I worry about 404 issues if:

1. I move my Laravel folder into a subfolder,
2. Rename home_assets in the future

I'm looking for a solution like:

```
Url::to_home_assets_image('origami/logo.png');
```

`Url` will take care of paths. If I move Laravel into `a/b/c/` folder, then it should understand public folder should be in `a/b/c/public/`.

`::to_home_assets_image` should work like a constant. `home_assets_image` constant/function/object (whatever you want to call it as) should refer to `'home_assets/image/'`.

Something like this: `Url::to_home_assets_image('origami/logo.png');` should work.

What do you think? I worry too much or it is something that has to be done to avoid folder issues?

Ps: I can't use `HTML::image()`. It will break the first example cause it will add an  tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve what you're after with `<img src="{{URL::to_asset('images/original/logo.jpg')}}">`.  It would be more work to get those URLs in your CSS styles, but is technically posible.  However, assuming all your assets are stored in `/public`, then url('../images/image.ext') will work fine.  If you need to change your asset folder path, you can set an `asset_url` config variable in your `/application/config/application.php`.

Comment: Where to_asset() points to? My folder is like /public/js|css|images for generalized things, but I use it like public/home_theme/js|css|images and public/admin_theme/js|css|images for different themes so they don't conflict.

Comment: to_asset will point to public/.  So you can do URL::to_asset('admin_theme/css/foo.css');  There's no way that I know of to create your own url shortcuts outside of extending the URL class or creating a helper somewhere in your own code.  If you do want to go that route, One suggestion is using `View::share('admin_theme',URL::to_asset('admin_theme/')` in your base controller (or perhaps paths.php if you're not using controllers).  That way, you can do `{{ $admin_theme.'css/foo.css' }}`. Repeat the process as necessary for home_theme or anywhere else you'd like.